# Android: AWS DynamoDB null pointer exception for mapper

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, nullpointerexception, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am trying to add the cognito user ID to my DynamoDB Users table.

So in the identityManager.java class I am calling a function in the background to to create the user in the table.

I am getting a null pointer exception on the mapper.save(user) line but not sure why.

This is where I create the mapper:

```
public class IdentityManager {

   DynamoDBMapper mapper;

    public IdentityManager() {
        mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
    }
```

This is where I call the add user function:

```
 private void onCognitoSuccess() {
            handler.onSuccess(currentIdentityProvider);

            // Adds a new user
            new addUser().execute();
```

This is the add user function:

```
public class addUser extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

            UserDatabaseMappingAdapter user = new UserDatabaseMappingAdapter();
            user.setUserID("testUserID");
            mapper.save(user);
            return null;
        }
```

This is the getter/setter userDataBaseMappingAdapter:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "UsersBeta")
public class UserDatabaseMappingAdapter {

    private String userid;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "UserID")
    public String getUserID() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
```

And this is the full error I am getting:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.amazonaws.mobile.user.IdentityManager$addUser.doInBackground(IdentityManager.java:522)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
at java.lang.Thread.run
```

Comment: @LaurentY you edit it it mark me down and don't even try to help me with my problem poor form.

Comment: with the code snippet posted here, I cannot say why it is null. Please post the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

`mapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper()` is giving value or null.

Also ensure that mapper is passed to Class addUser before executing the code `mapper.save(user);`

Comment: yes it is null but I don't understand why it would be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear you are having this issue leading to an NPE. The reason this is occurring is likely because the AWSMobileClient is not yet initialized at the time that the IdentityManager is created. The IdentityManger is responsible for creating the credentials provider that is needed to get the dynamo client, so it cannot be retrieved from the IdentityManager's constructor.

I suggest trying to call AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper() from your async task addUser.doInBackground() method.

One other thing to point out is that if you set a member variable that needs to be accessed across threads you should declare it as volatile or if it is set in a constructor it should be declared final if it will be accessed from another thread.

I look forward to hearing back from you.